# Alfresco CMIS soap where to start

Tags: soap, alfresco, navision

I need to integrate alfresco with Navision 2013 and I focused on alfresco web service (soap binding) to create a connector beetween the two systems.I searched a lot in alfresco wiki and forum but I didn't find nothing about SOAP version. Someone can give me an overview and links where to find some of usefull articles for making basic operations (upload, download documetents, create folder, get workflow information)using cmis soap services?

Comment: Did you try [the Alfresco CMIS Resources page](http://cmis.alfresco.com/) and [Apache Chemistry](http://chemistry.apache.org/)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll take a look at your links

Answer (score 3):

Alfresco CMIS specs: http://cmis.alfresco.com/

Apache OpenCMIS Java Clients: http://chemistry.apache.org/java/opencmis.html
You can select to use the SOAP binding.

Apache Workbench: http://chemistry.apache.org/java/developing/tools/dev-tools-workbench.html
With this tool you can test your CMIS server with all the needed services.